# Iterating over columns from two dataframes to estimate correlation and p-value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, correlation

I am trying to estimate Pearson's correlation coefficient and P-value from the corresponding columns of two dataframes. I managed to write this code so far but it is just providing me the results from the last columns. Need some help with this code. Also, want to save the outputs in a new dataframe.

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import scipy as sp
import scipy.stats  as stats

df_1 = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_excel('15_Oct_Yield_A.xlsx'))
df_2= pd.DataFrame(pd.read_excel('Oct_Z_index.xlsx'))

for column in df_1.columns[1:]:
    for column in df_2.columns[1:]:
        x = (df_1[column])
        y = (df_2[column])
    correl = stats.pearsonr(x, y)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your looping setup is incorrect on a couple measures...  You are using the same variable name in both for-loops which is going to cause problems.  Also, you are computing `correl` outside of your inner loop... etc.

What you want to do is loop over the columns with 1 loop, assuming that both data frames have the same column names.  If they do not, you will need to take extra steps to find the common column names and then iterate over them.

Something like this should work:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import scipy as sp
import scipy.stats  as stats

df_1 = pd.DataFrame({   'A':    ['dog', 'pig', 'cat'],
                        'B':    [0.25, 0.50, 0.75],
                        'C':    [0.30, 0.40, 0.90]})
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({   'A':    ['bird', 'monkey', 'rat'],
                        'B':    [0.20, 0.60, 0.90],
                        'C':    [0.80, 0.50, 0.10]})

results = dict()
for column in df_1.columns[1:]:
    correl = stats.pearsonr(df_1[column], df_2[column])
    results[column] = correl

print(results)
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the mistake I was doing. This solution works fine!